# Magento 1.9 : Slow order creation from backend

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, backend, performance, profiler

One of our Magento clients has reported that creating orders from the backend (manually eg customer ordering over the phone) is intermittently very slow.

Each checkout step (whenever the spinning 'Please wait' wheel appears) can take anywhere from 5-20s to load:

[image]

To check/confirm this we have installed AOE Profiler and have set it to profile the requests made to the `/index.php/admin/sales_order_create` URL.

The profiler has identified that the most common source of slowness is the `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start/start` event. We have seen that event take between 5-40s as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Saving an order can take anywhere from 10-40 seconds (10s is normal whereas anything greater than 15s is excessive). MySQL slow query logging is enabled and it has not logged any slow queries so the slowness does not appear to be due to database queries.

The system has 12,000 products and approx 10,000 orders. Most orders only have 2-3 order items.

The site is running Magento 1.9.3.8 on dedicated hardware and the system load is always low (eg < 0.5). The site gets low traffic and there is rarely more than 1 customer browsing at a time so there does not appear to be a bottleneck as far as resource allocation is concerned.

**Additional information requested:**

- MySQL server is hosted locally on same dedicated server as web server
- MySQL version is 5.1.73 (most recent version supported by CentOS 6.10)
- RAM is 64GB (~40GB currently free)
- my.cnf: https://pastebin.com/Dq2jYKDa
- SHOW GLOBAL STATUS result: https://pastebin.com/Bmy7B8n5
- SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES result: https://pastebin.com/fghk0UkL
- MySQLTuner output: https://pastebin.com/xqKzCSxd
- Other commands: https://pastebin.com/D3TFMae9

How can we troubleshoot/fix the slow session start which is causing the slowness?

Comment: It would really depend on custom code done on your instance around session generation, so start debugging there, tbh it is not a general issue it is specific to your site and connot be reproduced to give you any reliable answer

Comment: @chris Please view my profile, Network profile for contact info, including my Skype ID and get in touch with me, please.

Comment: @chris Additional info requested. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report if readily available 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @chris  Without the information requested above, this is a BEST GUESS.  Suggestion for your my.cnf or my.ini [mysqld] section - not nicely formatted as ANSWER would take care of the line spacing.  thread_cache_size=100  innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  innodb_flushing_avg_loops=10  innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8  would all be safe and may reduce CPU cycles significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for your ulimit -a to consider please

ulimit -n 48000  # from 1024 to enable more OS file handles to be active
   to make this persistent across OS shutdown/restart, 
   review this url for similar OS instructions 
https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section  (RPS = Rate Per Second)

```
# 20180827 0149 from mysqlservertuning.com
# query_cache_size=0  # from 64M conserve RAM for useful operations, QC not in use
# max_connections=100  # from 200, max_used_connections in 4 days = 11
# read_rnd_buffer_size=512K  # from ~4M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next
# thread_cache_size=100  # from 4 to reduce threads_created of 1423 in 4 days
# key_cache_division_limit=50  # from 100 to reduce key_reads RPS
```

Save your current my.ini in \history with DATED timed filename such as 20180827hhmm-my.cnf to allow going back to last working my.ini quickly.

Copy this BLOCK (including the leading date and our web site name)to END of your [mysqld] section and ENABLE one change per DAY by removing leading # and spacecharacter, monitor before moving on to next change.

Disable EARLIER same NAMED variable with leading # and space bar, to avoid confusion. In 5 years you will still have history of my.ini changes with approximate dates.

Normally only ONE change per day, monitor before moving to next change. 
If a change seems detrimental, go back to last working my.ini and let us know, please.

For additional suggestions (and you have many more opportunities) please view profile, Network profile.

Comment: @chris Thanks for the upvote and Accept.  Have you already applied all the suggestions?  What is typical response time now, please give BEFORE and AFTER recap.  Thanks, Wilson

Comment: We are currently implementing each suggestion, one per day. Last night we did the `read_rnd_buffer_size` tweak which seems to have made a significant improvement to the time taken to save a manual order - but this may well be a coincidence. All orders saved today were 6-7s whereas previously this was 10-20s. I won't jump to any conclusions yet. Either way though, mega thanks.

Comment: @chris One a day is the best policy.  Please document with leading # in your my.cnf the date change was made and apparent difference so the next person looking at your configuration does not arbitrarily make it larger, thinking MORE has to be better.  Thanks for keeping me posted.  And please visit my web site.

Comment: @chris Have you implemented all 5 suggestions?  How is the instance running for your customers/associates?

Comment: We implemented all the suggested MySQL tweaks, but none of them addressed the original issue of slow backend order creation. However, we finally tracked this down to an issue relating to the cache being too large. We are now pruning Magento's cache folder every few hours and the performance is normal again. Thanks for your time and suggestions!

Comment: @chris What shows on your ulimit -a report for 'open files' ?  You had been restricted to 1024 open file handles on Aug 26, 18.  Glad you are making progress.  On my site, SHOP, My NEXT 30 Global Variable Suggestions would be very helpful for your instance performance optimization.

Comment: `ulimit -a` is showing 48000 for open files. At the moment MySQL doesn't seem to be slowing us down, but will potentially make contact with you in the future.